# PHP script timeout when I use sleep()

Tags: php, nginx

I have problem with php script timeout when I use sleep()

this code:

```
<?php      
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo 'Begin ...<br />';
flush();
ob_flush();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $i . '<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(65);
}
echo 'End ...<br />';
flush();
ob_flush();
?>
```

When I execute this code and wait 60 seconds script has stop working.

This server config

php.ini

```
max_execution_time 3600;
```

nginx.conf

```
keepalive_timeout 3600;
```

How do I config for solve this problem?

Excuse me, I'm not good english.

Comment: Not the right timeout for nginx...  What do you mean by the script has stopped working?  Error messages?  HTTP Response Code?

Comment: The script has stopped working after wait 60 seconds. Not have error message. And http response code when execute this code is 200.

Comment: @Devon Update-- when I execute on firefox after wait 60 seconds it show error "The connection was reset, The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

Comment: You need to set [proxy_send_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_send_timeout) if you `proxy_pass`, or [fastcgi_send_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_send_timeout) if you `fastcgi_pass`. And [keepalive_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_timeout) is something completely different.

Comment: @IvanTsirulev I set proxy_send_timeout is 3600, fastcgi_send_timeout is 3600 and  keepalive_timeout is 3600 are not working.

Comment: Did you reload your Nginx configuration with `sudo service nginx reload`? Don't forget to test it with `sudo nginx -t` before you do it. Also, modern browsers tend to cache 50x responses. Did you clear your browser's cache?

Comment: Sure, I reload nginx before test again. And not working.

Comment: use set_time_limit(0);

Comment: @bob_1982 I add "set_time_limit(0);" on first line. It's not working.

Answer (score -1):

Show your nginx configs.

You need increase `proxy_read_timeout` in nginx configuration.